# Proper formatting for pattern string in typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, regex, input

I want to create a string month that holds

```
 let month: string = 'pattern="^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$"';
```

I would like to store it in the variable but I get an error stating

```
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

What changes do I need to make in my angular install or the formatting of the above mentioned pattern.

Comment: You have to escape slashes, for instance the \ of \d with \\d, the same goes for the other slashes.